# R: How do I multiply a lower dimension data frame with a higher one as a scalar

Tags: r

I have a Data Frame `P` which has factor variables "m" and "q". Also, a Data Frame `D` which has factor variables "m", "q", "f" and "t". I want to get a new data frame H with factors "m", "q", "f" and "t where.

```
H(m,f,q,t) = P(m,q) * D(m,q,f,t) for all m,q,f and t.
```

Essentially, I want to merge the two data frames on the shared variables 'm' and 'q' and multiply their `Val` columns

The data is saved in the following format:

```
> head(P)
                    m     q Val
raw1.Prio0       raw1 Prio0    0.5
raw1.Prio1       raw1 Prio1    0.7
raw2.Prio0       raw2 Prio0    1
raw2.Prio1       raw2 Prio1    1
product.Prio0 product Prio0    0.5
product.Prio1 product Prio1    1

> head(D)
                          m     q f   t       Val
product.Prio0.a.P01 product Prio0 a P01  445.6159
product.Prio0.a.P02 product Prio0 a P02  445.6159
product.Prio0.a.P03 product Prio0 a P03  445.6159
product.Prio0.a.P04 product Prio0 a P04 1445.6159
product.Prio0.a.P05 product Prio0 a P05 1445.6159
product.Prio0.b.P01 product Prio0 b P01  176.0000
```

The Result should look like this:

```
> head(H)
                          m     q f   t     Val
product.Prio0.a.P01 product Prio0 a P01 222.808
product.Prio0.a.P02 product Prio0 a P02 222.808
product.Prio0.a.P03 product Prio0 a P03 222.808
product.Prio0.a.P04 product Prio0 a P04 722.808
product.Prio0.a.P05 product Prio0 a P05 722.808
product.Prio0.b.P01 product Prio0 b P01  88.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
H<-merge(P,D, by=c("m","q"))

H$Val <- H$Val.x * H$Val.y
```

It outputs:

```
> H
        m     q Val.x f   t     Val.y     Val
1 product Prio0   0.5 a P01  445.6159 222.808
2 product Prio0   0.5 a P02  445.6159 222.808
3 product Prio0   0.5 a P03  445.6159 222.808
4 product Prio0   0.5 a P04 1445.6159 722.808
5 product Prio0   0.5 a P05 1445.6159 722.808
6 product Prio0   0.5 b P01  176.0000  88.000
```